# Python 3 Tkinter Dark Theme

Tags: tkinter, python-3.8

I want to build a tkinter app and I don't know how to set a dark mode theme to the window, Text, Button and ScrolledText.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, but can you show as what youve tried? So we can tell whats wrong and whats not.

Comment: @CoolCloud I haven't tried because I don't know how to activate a dark theme. Do you have a sample?

Comment: It actually depends upon your code, there is no inbuilt way, but take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35V5r6S2_FA) for an idea.

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks! It's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter provides themes like clam, classic, etc. You can also make your own. Check https://rdbende.github.io/tkinter-docs/tutorials/how-to-use-themes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import customtkinter

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.is_on = True
        self.lights_control = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.lights_control.grid(row=3, column=0, rowspan=1, padx=(5, 5), pady=(10, 10), sticky="new")

        self.dark_theme_switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.lights_control, text="DarkTheme",
                                                  command= self.dark_theme)
        self.dark_theme_switch.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")

    
    def dark_theme(self, event=None):
        if self.is_on:
            customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
            self.is_on = False
            print(self.is_on)
        else:
            customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Light")
            self.is_on = True
            print(self.is_on)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

This should help you..!

[image: Light Theme]
[image: Dark Theme]